# Обработка multipart/form-data на сервере NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, formdata

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь обработать `multipart/form-data` и решительно ничего не получается. По рекомендации Гугла решил использовать модуль `formidable`. Вроде бы все делаю, как рекомендуют, но модуль выбрасывает ошибку:`Error: bad content-type header, no multipart boundary`. При этом логи показывают, что `content-type` `multipart/form-data`. 
Код сервера:

```
server.on("request", function(req, res){
var urlParse = url.parse(req.url);
if (urlParse.pathname == "/load") {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
            if(err) console.error(err);
            console.log(fields);
            console.log(files);
        });
    //чтобы проверить, что запрос приходит раскомментируйте код ниже и 
    //закомментируйте выше
        // var data ="";
        // req.on('data', function(chunk){
        //  data += chunk;
        // })
        // req.on("end", function(){
        //  console.log(data);
        //  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        //  res.end(data);
        // })
    };
    }
```

js

```
finishBtn.onclick = function(){
    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.baseIdForm);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/load");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
    xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState != 4) return;
            if(xhr.status == 200){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);

            }
        }
}
```

html

```
<form name="baseIdForm">
    <input type="text" name="pact" placeholder="№ договора" style="">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Название" size="40">
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Цена">
    </form>
     <button type="button" id="finishBtn">Создать</button>
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=someString` не валиден без директивы `boundary`.
Вы можете опустить `xhr.setRequestHeader` в Вашем коде, так как браузер всегда отправляет `FormData` как `multipart/form-data`, указывая в заголовке свой `boundary`.

Однако, `multipart/form-data` не самый хороший вариант для отправки подобных форм. Лучше использовать `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Но придется вручную формировать данные из формы.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!  Эти формы использовал в качестве теста. Так-то я картинки хотел отправлять.