# Как отправить File (фотографию) через Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend, fetch

Мне нужно отправить на сервер структуру данных вида:

`{
    myForm: {
      photo:File, 
      name:"вася"
   }, 
   token:"test"
}`

При том в File хранится фотка загруженная пользователем.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста как это можно сделать?(желательно через fetch)**

Я пытался сделать это отправляя обычный json, но после выполнения JSON.stringify, File превращался в пустой объект....

Я так же пытался я использовать FormData, но в этом случае я не знаю как сохранить структуру объекта, ведь в свойство FormData, можно записать только строчку, File или Blob, и как я понимаю нельзя записать js объект myForm.....

**Нужно без jq, на нативном js**

Comment: посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381936/ и https://hostenko.com/wpcafe/hacks/ajax-zagruzka-faylov-na-server-s-pomoshhyu-jquery/

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/upload-file-and-json-data-in-the-same-post-request-using-jquery-ajax#14737000007356179

Comment: нужно без jq, на нативном js.

Comment: добавьте код ajax

Comment: @Дмытрык, я просто использую js метод fetch. Сначала передавал в fetch, объект пропученный через json.json.stringify, но это не работало т.к. мой file после stringify превращался в пустой объект. Потом пытался через FormData, но в форм дата, как я понял, нельзя добавлять объекты по этому не получилось сделать вложенность объекта в объект....А у Вас нормально отправляется файл?

Comment: та я тоже помучился с этой формДатой. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745478/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-multipart-form-data-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-nodejs