# Как в node.js руками распарсить form-data?

Tags: node.js, express, formdata

Сейчас реализую аплоад файлов на сервер.
Файлы приходят в пост запросе с заголовком multipart/form-data.

Пробовал библиотеки multer, multiparty, busboy. Они конечно крутые и многое делают за меня (особенно multer понравился), но все же не обрабатывают не все кейсы которые мне нужны.
В итоге все же осознал необходимость написать свой велосипед.

Но и от библиотек отказаться трудно, т.к. они парсят формдату и дают мне содержимое текстовых полей формы.

Есть ли способ самому руками раскодировать формдату и узнать содержимое полей формы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745478/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-multipart-form-data-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-nodejs - гляньте тут, может поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, юзайте busboy. Он из всех библиотек самый низкоуровневый. Текстовые поля парсит, а на каждый файл в реквесте создает readableStream, который можно обработать как хочешь.