# Как получить содержимое файла из multipart form data в node.js?

Tags: node.js, request, fileupload

Я отправляю Json файл с клиента на restify сервер как multipart form data. Для получения файла на сервере я использую `restify.plugins.multipartBodyParser()`. Мне нужно получить содержимое файла на сервере в виде строки или json объекта, без сохранения файла на диск. Как мне это сделать? Получаемый файл имеет формат File()

```
server.post('/upload', (req,res,next) => {
   const file = req.files['file']
   const fileContent = ??????(file)
   const myObj = JSON.parse(fileContent)
   res.send('ok')
})
```

Из multipart-form-data файл я уже получил. Меня интересует как достать его содержимое.

Comment: я может не знаю специфики вашей задачи. но зачем вам отправлять json через multipart form data? почему бы не отправить эти данные в теле(body) post-запроса, а на сервере разобрать его через bodyParser (или какую там библиотечку для этого используют в restify)?

Comment: Специфика в том, что у меня на сервере есть справочник, который хранится в базе данных. И есть json файлы, которые содержат записи для этого справочника. Ты загружаешь на сервер эти файлы, для того, чтоб дополнить или обновить справочник. Сегодня используется json, но в будущем может быть xml или любой другой формат. Т.е. мне нужно загружать на сервер именно файл, считывать на сервере его содержимое, пропускать через нужный мне парсер и обновлять бд.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обработка multipart/form-data на сервере NodeJs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745478/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-multipart-form-data-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-nodejs)

Comment: Это не дубликат. Даже не близко.

Comment: А почему не дубликат? В том вопросе и ответе, есть все данные, которые помогут решить Вашу проблему. В вопросе описано, как обрабатывается formdata, в ответе указано, где ошибка и чего не хватает

Comment: Там проблема с получением данных. Я уже данные получил, и есть куча способов как их сохранить на диск. Но у меня имеется файл в формате File, мне нужно его переконвертировать в строку. Там у человека совсем другая проблема.

Comment: Я решительно не понимаю Вашу проблему. Вы получили файл в multipart-form-data? Так, по идее, он у Вас уже в виде строки. Или, после получения, Вы делали с ним какие-то манипуляции? П.С. если хотите ответить кому-то в комментарии - перед ником ставьте знак `@`

Comment: немного покопавшись в тайпингах библиотеки, я пришел к выводу что multipartBodyParser по умолчанию сразу сохраняет файл на диск. а в переменной file из второй сторчки вашего примера находится следующий объект: {path: string, type: string}. предлагаю при конфигурации multipartBodyParser передать переметр multipartFileHandler. задайте поиск по этому слову здесь http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/